# Why doesn't my wireless keyboard work with my USB port replicator?

Tags: usb-3, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

I have a Lenovo x240 with Lenovo USB 3.0 Dock (port replicator) and Lenovo Ultraslim Wireless Keyboard and Mouse. The keyboard and mouse work fine when plugged in to the laptop directly, but not when I plug in to the USB Dock. The keyboard will work most of the time, but the mouse jerks around and is slow to react when clicking the buttons.

The point of the dock is so that I can just plug a single cable in everything just works (keyboard, mouse, network, monitor, printer). Everything else works, except the keyboard and mouse.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: Ate there any specific drivers for the dock that need to be installed? We had a similar issue with another brand dock - the USBs worked for memory sticks but other stuff wouldn't work properly until we found some drivers for the USB controller chipset that the dock used. Once installed everything worked.

Comment: The dock has specific drivers, which I have installed. I don't think I did the same for the keyboard and mouse though. Not sure if that could cause a problem, so maybe I'll download those and have another attempt.

Comment: Update. After re-installing the drivers the keyboard began working, but the mouse is unusable, jerking around and not tracking as expected. I've updated the questions accordingly.

Comment: @JohnnyMaelstrom are the batteries on the wireless mouse new? or are they lacking charge? because that can cause the mouse to pick up the sensor very sparsely and work as you stated above

Comment: I was just about to add something similar. Although it may not be pretty (and highly illogical) but can you put the mouse/keyboard USB receiver on a USB extensions cable and place it close to where the mouse/keyboard are to be used... If your docking station is, say, under your desk (to keep things tidy) then there may be some interference (plus what Nathan Taylor says about batteries) causing some issues...?

Comment: @NathanTaylor the whole system is brand new with fresh batteries all out of the box from Lenovo. Sensible idea though.

Comment: @BigChris It may be worth trying your suggestion, but the docking station is actually as close to the keyboard and mouse as when plugged  in to the laptop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with the docking station.  USB wireless receivers do not work well on them. The problem resides within the USB 3.0 hardware causing interruption of the usb wireless signal.

An extension cable may work. It will get the wireless receiver further from the USB 3.0 signals.

If this does not work then you must plug the receiver directly into the laptop or use a wired laptop and mouse into the docking station.  Other options are to see if you can find a bluetooth keyboard and mouse as they will work as well.

Comment: An extension cable may work. It will get the wireless receiver further from the USB 3 signals.

Comment: Is it the fact that my keyboard/mouse dongle is running over USB 3.0 on the dock and combined with other signals on that cable or that USB 3.0 itself is emitting some electromagnetic noise itself causing a problem? I think it's the former so an extension cable wouldn't help because the USB dongle would still be connected to the same USB 3.0 dock and suffer the same interruptions.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said. It's the electromagnetic interference. I have a Toshiba Dynadock U3.0 and only wired peripherals work. I have however found a solution to this problem, just use  the wireless receiver with a cheap USB Hub that you connect to the dock. Not very elegant, but it works.